# Sql Server get row closest (in the future) to today

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table that contains a history of items with a startdate (datetime) - it should only allow one single item against a date.  There's a validation procedure that will take a date and return a code (success/failure reason code) along with the 'next' historical item closest to today.

If this is the table data (id date title):

```
1 16/05/2010 'item 1'
2 17/05/2010 'item 2'
3 20/05/2010 'item 3'
```

I want to validate an entry:

```
exec Validate '18/05/2010' 'item 4'
```

Would return me: '**item 4**' because the entry is valid and although the data hasn't been committed, it returns my new entry as the next available item because it's closest (in the future) to today.

```
exec Validate '24/05/2010' 'item 5'
```

Should return me: '**Item 3**'.  The date is also valid, but there is a record earlier then then new date, but later than today.

Comment: Can you explain the item thing again please? Why item 4 gets no match when there is a later date (for item 3) but item 5 gets data from item 3 row when this row is "before"

Comment: At the moment, this is only a validation routine and nothing is committed to the database - item 4 wouldn't exist in the table when 'item 5' was tested.  So the proc should return me whats closer to tomorrows date (maybe that's a better way to describe it) - a row, or whatever I've passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can base your checks on next query:

```
select min(startdate)
from itemstable
where datediff(d, getdate(), startdate)>0
    and datediff(d, startdate, @datetocheck)>=0
```

First clause checks for future startdates, second clause for startdates before or same as your supplied one.

(It's possible that some comparisons are wrong - happens always with date problems :))

Comment: Helpful, thanks.  I think I've got something working but it's not very graceful (return the result of your idea based on a further join, or simply select out the values passed into the proc).